# Как реализовать, чтобы данный скрипт срабатывал раз в 6сек.?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как реализовать, чтобы данный скрипт срабатывал раз в 6 сек.?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/Продажи/g, "Оплаты")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/продажи/g, "оплаты")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/Продажа/g, "Оплата")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/продажа/g, "оплата")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/заказа/g, "квитанции")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/Заказа/g, "Квитанции")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/Заказ/g, "Квитанция")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/заказ/g, "квитанция")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/балло/g, "балл.")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/товар/g, "квитанция")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/Товар/g, "Квитанция")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/товара/g, "квитанции")
  });
  $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/Товара/g, "Квитанции")
  });
});
```

Comment: Обернуть в `setInterval()`

Comment: "чтобы он срабатывал раз в 6сек., а не через 6сек. после загрузки страницы

Comment: Опечатался.....

Comment: как именно?можете дать более подробный ответ, как это "завернуть" в setInterval() ?

Comment: Ради интереса - а что происходит каждые 6 секунд, что контент постоянно обновляется и его нужно изменять? Если это после асинхронных действий, то setInterval - ненадежный вариант и надо использовать коллбеки к ним

Comment: @ДимаДиман тогда можно либо промисы, либо ещё обернуть в `setTimeout(,0)` и тогда привязываться к `document`

Comment: @doox911, про это и говорю. Либо promiss, либо коллбэки к функциям по типу $.ajax. А насчёт setTimeout(,0) - это для чего?

Comment: @ДимаДиман для рендеринга. Почитайте про even loop.

Comment: @doox911, хм, получается, небольшая оптимизация? ни разу такое не юзал) Возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
setInterval(() => {
  $(function() {
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/Продажи/g, "Оплаты")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/продажи/g, "оплаты")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/Продажа/g, "Оплата")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/продажа/g, "оплата")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/заказа/g, "квитанции")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/Заказа/g, "Квитанции")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/Заказ/g, "Квитанция")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/заказ/g, "квитанция")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/балло/g, "балл.")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/товар/g, "квитанция")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/Товар/g, "Квитанция")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/товара/g, "квитанции")
    });
    $('#transactions_filters, #transactions_cont').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace(/Товара/g, "Квитанции")
    });
  });
}, 6000);
```